# How can I reply to broadcast messages?

Tags: linux, wall

I received some messages here:

```
[root@localhost kvm]# 
Broadcast message from root@localhost.localdomain (pts/1) (Thu Jun  6 08:04:26 2019):

hello

Broadcast message from root@localhost.localdomain (pts/1) (Thu Jun  6 08:05:02 2019):

hello
```

How has this messagen been sent to me? And how can I reply to it?

Comment: If the other root is not you, and you don't have a clue who it might be, I'd start there: [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aside from the concerns that you host might be compromised, to broadcast a message to all users or users in a specific group, use `wall`

```
wall -g root "Hi there"
# Will send to all users in the root group
wall "hello, world"
# Will send to all logged in users
```

Also checkout `mesg` and `talk`.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a broadcast sent by someone logged in as root using the [`wall`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wall) utility.  You can use this same command to broadcast your own message.  Eg:

```
wall "Hello back"
```

Or

```
wall << EOF
hello back
EOF
```

If you just want to respond to a single user without broadcasting to everyone on your system you can use [`write`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/write):

```
write root << EOF
hello back
EOF
```

---

Obviously the fact that this says from root@localhost.localdomain infers that someone is logged in as `root`.  If you know that nobody but you is supposed to be logged in as root then [**take action**](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server) because it infers your machine has been compromised.